# I have created website in next js page is loading very slow at first time

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I created the app in next js first time when I opened any page it took 9 to 10 sec. But the second time when I click on the same page link it's open very fast. This is my app.js file code.

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { Sidenav } from '../components';

 function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
       const router = useRouter();
       const authPages = [
      '/error-illustration',
      '/error',
      '/password-reset-cover',
      '/password-reset-illustration',
      '/password-reset',
      '/sign-in-cover',
      '/sign-in-illustration',
      '/sign-in',
      '/sign-up-cover',
      '/sign-up-illustration',
      '/sign-up',
    ];

    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
          <title>Dashkit React</title>
        </Head>
        {!authPages.includes(router.pathname) && <Sidenav />}
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  }

  export default MyApp;
```

Comment: Can you try by removing !authPages.includes(router.pathname) condition. and see if it changes the response time

Comment: @PrabhjeevNijjar Hi tried but same time :(

Comment: You probably have some long running tasks ( ex. data fetching) that after the first render are cached. Are you using next.js ISR ?

Comment: @Nico No I have a simple page. yes I am using next.js

Comment: Try commenting out the sidenav import aswell

Comment: @PrabhjeevNijjarand side nav is only for the side nav bar how its impact for speed the same thing !authPages.includes(router.pathname)  this code is for authentication

Comment: Are you talking about starting the app via `next dev` ? In that case, I wouldn't worry, because it loads lots of development features. Try `next build && next start`, and see if it's faster (Even then it would be a little bit slower on first start, but not many seconds.)

Comment: @kca same thing happening at the production server also and I run the same command (next build && next start) Thank you!